# How could you differentiate if the bitcoin address is from master node or derived nodes?

Tags: address-generation, bip32-hd-wallets

Given that I have these two random generated bitcoin testnet addresses, could you tell if it is the bitcoin testnet, master node or derived nodes, if we discuss [bip-0032 spec (Master key generation)](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#master-key-generation)?

```
**master node (m)**
mn6tBTqAigmknKMkpT82VYLy272mfXYdqF

**derived node (m/0/999999'/0)**
myt7MRuUpXRDL3ht5E1oiP3yrKkekCzc4S
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this question is about whether other people can tell whether there is a relationship between these two addresses:
Just from the addresses, third parties cannot tell that the two addresses are related.

Third parties may be able to guess that they are associated by analysing the transaction graph, though.

Comment: so, if there are no transaction between each other, we cannot tell they have any relationship even if we undergo chain analysis, right?

Comment: Correct. To third parties the two addresses appear completely unrelated.